# Why does native one-time binding with the `::` expression not working in Angular 1.3.5

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know that AngularJS introduced a native one-time binding with the `::` expression. In my case it doesn't work, since the values still change, so please tell me I'm missing something.

Given this controller:

```
$scope.name = "Some Name";
$scope.changeName = function() {
    $scope.name = "Another Name";
}
```

And this HTML

```
<h1>{{::name}}</h1>
<button ng-click="changeName()">click me</button>
```

The name model value changes.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### EDIT: *(taken from comments)*

### **Remove the AngularJS Batarang extension from Chrome**

ORIGINAL ANSWER: (outdated)

Seems working for me.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.name = "Some Name";
  $scope.changeName = function() {
    $scope.name = "Another Name";
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <h1>{{::name}}</h1>
  <button ng-click="changeName()">click me</button>
  <p> {{name}} </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, it worked when I removed the AngularJS Batarang extension from Chrome (0.4.3). Phew.

Comment: having similar issue, removed batarang but so far still not working.. not throwing errors either, so it's interesting

Comment: @Omar F, same issue here. Man, I have been googling this forever.